# Repeating background not displaying

Tags: html, css

Ok, this is by far one of the strangest problems I have encountered in my css experience. I am trying to use some subtle patterns that repeat for a div on my webpage. Strange enough, whenever i try to set an pattern that is very white, the browser refuses to load the image. When I try to use a darker image, it works just fine. Now I know that the colour is obviously not the problem, but what am I missing. Here is the HTML/CSS:

```
#section1{
background-image: url("../images/as.png");
```

}

```
    <div id="section1">
     <div class="content98">
      <h1 id="h1d">De ce matest.ro?</h1>
       <div id="border">
        <img class="show" id="show1" src="images/untitled-2.png">
        <h2 id="dix">Obiective</h2>
        <hr>
        <div id="hided1"><p class="hiding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tellus lorem, feugiat ut condimentum ac, ultricies vitae nibh. Duis sed lacinia magna.>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    <br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: you're going to have to recreate this in a fiddle. Is the issue that you just cant see it when its white?

Comment: @jmore009 why a fiddle? SO has this functionality too ya know ;)

Comment: I'm using it mostly to mean "post a working example", doesnt specifically have to be a fiddle

Comment: Agreed with @jmore009, you're going to need to post a working demo to get a clear answer. But from what you've posted I'd say either the lighter image simply isn't loading, or your screen's settings are set so that an image with such low contrast simply appears white.

Comment: @jlego my screen is calibrated so colors should not be a problem. I have tried it on a new html and the background works... I deleted all the css and js links but it still is not working. I will post a detailed demo asap

Comment: I really do not know what could prevent a background to display. It is so strange that it works with some png but it doesn't with others...i dont know if it is important but i take my background images from subtlepatterns.

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu subtle patterns is fine, can you post a demo?

Comment: @jmore009 yeah nice. found the problem. it's happening because of OS X. when i run my webpage on w7 it's perfectly fine. so the code is ok after all.

Answer (score 0):

First check your `body` `background color` white or change and see. Then Check in inspect element of browser in style box that your property is strikeout or not.

```
#section1{
background-image: url("../images/as.png");
}
```

And then add `background-repeat:repeat;` to your image like this.

```
#section1{
background-image: url("../images/as.png");
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

even like this you can write

```
#section1{
background:url("../images/as.png") repeat;
}
```